# Who owns the login information for a website? A client or designer.

Tags: legal

My client has paid for his website but not the other consulting work that is done by our company. He is refusing to pay for 2 months worth of consulting but is demanding his login info for the backend of his site.

We didn't intentionally keep the login information from him. We had a great relationship until recently. So do we legally need to hand that information over to him?  We have no written contract in place.

Comment: Legally or ethically? if legally, we cannot provide sound legal advice. Legal.StackExchange would do better. Ethically, picture being in their position: what would you expect?

Comment: Who owns the website?

Comment: If you were paid to do the backend. But offcourse you csn jsut give him the data as agreed and stop hosting it for him.

Answer (score 0):

Give them the version that doesn't include the consulting work you did. If they aren't paying for hosting stop hosting but give them a copy of the version they did pay for with passwords of their site. Legally, you should ask a professional, especially since there isn't a contract in place. They will want to see emails of your work requests to show proof those things were ordered more than likely. Good luck!

Comment: So we are not hosting the site. It is hosted at godaddy under our clients account which we set up for him. He has no login info because we never got around to giving it to him. Now he is refusing to pay us 12,000. This is tricky because it's a lot of money and we just want him to pay it. We are not vengeful but it doesn't seem right that he can get away with nonpayment and we should just hand over the login. We will never see that money if we do that. We really like this guy and don't want to go to court over this.

Comment: Zach, we would never stiff anyone so I would expect that no one should stiff us.